# kotlin generics: Cannot infer type parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

I need a Collection in Kotlin to contain only elements implementing a given interface.

For example: a Map containing Collection of Animals:

```
interface Animal { val name: String }
data class Monkey(override val name: String): Animal
data class Snake(override val name: String): Animal
```

From reading the documentation and blogs and SO questions, I wrote this code that uses the Generics **in** keyword:

```
class Test {
    private val data = HashMap<String, ArrayList<in Animal>>()        
    init {
        data.put("Monkeys", arrayListOf(Monkey("Kong"), Monkey("Cheetah")))
        data.put("Snakes", arrayListOf(Snake("Monthy"), Snake("Kaa")))
    }        
}
```

Now I want to add a method in the Test class that reads the content of 'data', for example to print it to the console:

```
fun printAll() {
   data.forEach { collectionName: String, animals: ArrayList<in Animal> -> 
       println(collectionName)
       animals.forEach { animal: Animal ->
           println("\t$animal")
       }
    }
}
```

If I do that, I have a compilation error:

```
Error:(27, 21) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: Iterable<Any?>  arguments: ((Any?) -> Unit)
receiver: Iterable<Animal>  arguments: ((Animal) -> Unit)
can be applied to
receiver: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<in Animal> /* = java.util.ArrayList<in Animal> */  arguments: ((Animal) -> Unit)
```

My solution is to force my animal to a an ArrayList<**out** Animal>:

```
...
(animals as ArrayList<out Animal>).forEach { animal: Animal ->
    println("\t$animal")
}
...
```

But I'm not sure that this is the best way to write this kind of code.
Is there a better way to tell Kotlin that I want to use sub types in generics for both producers and consumers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you don't need the `in` keyword in the type of `data`.

Using `in` here means that you want the type arguments of those `ArrayList`s to be *at least as general* as `Animal`, meaning that an `ArrayList<in Animal>` may actually be parameterized with a supertype of `Animal` as well: you could even put an `ArrayList<Any>` into the map, which makes it clear that it's not type-safe to expect the lists to hold only `Animal`s.

Consider removing the `in` keyword and leaving just `ArrayList<Animal>` (or even `List<Animal>`, which is the interface for a read-only list):

```
private val data = HashMap<String, List<Animal>>()

init {
    data.put("Monkeys", listOf(Monkey("Kong"), Monkey("Cheetah")))
    data.put("Snakes", listOf(Snake("Monthy"), Snake("Kaa")))
}

fun printAll() {
    data.forEach { collectionName: String, animals: List<Animal> ->
        println(collectionName)
        animals.forEach { animal: Animal ->
            println("\t$animal")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, switching to immutable `List`s has an added benefit: it means that one can now treat `listOf(Monkey("Kong"), Monkey("Cheetah"))` as a `List<Monkey>` rather than `List<Animal>`.

Comment: this solution works well with the MutableList interface too, wich is convenient if I need a function that retrieve a list in order to modify it.

Comment: It is more common to see the `in`/`out` generic keywords in class signatures to define whether the class "consumes" or "produces" that type. You can read about these keywords here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance